# Anylogic Parameter Variation Experiment: In which way do I use the "Expression"-column to vary boolean parameters in their permitted states?

Tags: parameters, expression, anylogic

I set up a parameter variation experiment in AnyLogic in which I want to vary boolean parameters. In essence, there are 20 of these boolean parameters (parameter01 - parameter20) in a specified order, I try to simulate every possible combination of parameter values. The only restriction is that two consecutive parameters can't both be *true* (so if parameter01 is *true*, parameter02 can't be, and so on).

What I tried to do was to use the "Expression" column in Freeform Variation and formulate rules for every parameter. The code I wrote for parameter01 was, for example, `(parameter01 && !parameter02) || (!parameter01 && parameter02) || (!parameter01 && !parameter02)`. As you can probably tell, I tried to code every allowed value combination for parameter01 and parameter02, only excluding the case in which both are *true*, which isn't allowed. Unfortunately, this didn't work as intended, as Anylogic set every parameter to *false* in every simulation run.

Can you tell me what I did wrong or, more importantly, do you have a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write a function that returns the correct parameter value for each parameter and iteration number, i.e.

```
myFunction(int ParamNumber, int iterationNumber) {
    // write code here to satisfy your constraint
}
```

Call that function in the expression section for each parameter, setting the individual arguments accordingly. You can get the current iteration number using `getCurrentIteration()`

Best prepare the logic using Excel but it is probably not rocket science :)